# base64 encode, nodejs c++ python's result is diffrent

Tags: node.js, base64

nodejs:

```
var test = 'VdEU+Q2J5qfwsn9xshAcEImDSnxTR8RkRLlLmyNaeos=';

var result = new Buffer(test, 'base64').toString()
//var buf = Buffer.from(test, 'base64');
//var result = new Buffer(test, 'base64').toString("utf8");
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("test.txt",result,function(e){//会先清空原先的内容
   if(e) throw e;
})
```

python:

```
import base64

result = base64.b64decode('VdEU+Q2J5qfwsn9xshAcEImDSnxTR8RkRLlLmyNaeos=')
file_object = open('thefile.txt', 'w')
file_object.write(result)
file_object.close( )
```

c++: (I use libcef's base library's base64):

```
const std::string kText = "VdEU+Q2J5qfwsn9xshAcEImDSnxTR8RkRLlLmyNaeos=";

std::string encoded;
base::Base64Decode(kText, &encoded);

FILE *pFile = fopen("1.txt", "wb+");
fwrite(encoded.c_str(), encoded.length(), 1, pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

the result is python c++ is the same, but nodejs is different

Comment: Which one do you think is correct and why?

Comment: python c++ is correct.  i use a python api which is used in openid, but i create a nodejs api , the wrong is this place, because it's diffent when base64 decode

Comment: @stone_jb cud you show the outputs also here

Comment: @Iceman, John Zwinck have solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to not call `toString()`:

```
var result = new Buffer(test, 'base64');
```

Then the Node code does the same as the others.

Comment: @Iceman: Because `toString()` re-encodes the data, but you want the raw bytes.